Unable to set UV Vertex values to < -10 or > +10
Blender 4.1, never saw this in 3.x.
I'm trying to manually adjust the UV Vertex values of some vertexes. I'm finding that Blender won't let me assign values higher than 10 or less than -10.
Here I have a vertex selected, and I want to change the "X" vertex value:

If I manually enter a value between -10 and +10, it works. But if I enter a value outside of that range, blender ignores it and leaves the value unchanged. This also affects the way those Range inputs behave when I click and drag left-right on them to adjust the value, or click the "<" and ">" buttons to increment and decrement the values. (They're locked to -10 > +10).
I don't see anywhere in the Settings to change this range or remove the restriction. This doesn't appear to apply to other value inputs that I've noticed so far. Hopefully I'm just overlooking something really simple. Thanks.

I don't know if there's a proper solution, but as a workaround:
Scaling Workaround

.D Set Pivot Point to 2D Cursor.
A Select all points.
S.01↩ Enter Scale the coordinates to 1% of their original value.
Now you're still under the limit of $[-10, +10]$ range, but when you scale back in the next point, it effectively becomes $[-1000, +1000]$.
Once you're finished, to scale back reapply p 1., then S.100↩ Enter.

❗ Keep in mind you can introduce a floating point error, e.g. a coordinate 1.00001 becomes 0.099999 (at least as displayed in the UI, the actual values stored may be a little different still but I didn't bother to use python API to read the real values)
Overextend workaround
As annoying as it is for many points, it doesn't introduce any inaccuracies and doesn't corrupt existing coordinates. It's also faster for a single/a handful of points*:

.D Set Pivot Point to 2D Cursor.
Select a point.
SX0↩ Enter Set it's $x$ coordinate to 0.
GX, type the desired coordinate, then ↩ Enter - the Translate operator apparently ignores the limitation.
Obviously you can replace X with Y to set the $y$ coordinate. Or just don't use these keys in the instructions, and at the end press F9 to bring the operator window and manually put the desired coordinates.

Alternatively:

Select a point.
G↩ Enter or G click. If you want to make sure the point doesn't move in this step, consider instead G0↩ Enter.
In the operator pop-up (you can hit F9 to bring it up), set the coordinates that are even more beyond the limit, then the actual values you want to set.
Now in the Number panel you can set the desired values, because Blender will allow you to set values outside the allowed range - as long as they move closer to the allowed range.

* - actually points are dimensionless so you can grab infinite points in your hand (ackchyually in Blender there's limited precision of coordinates so for the biggest possible cube-shaped "hand" you can only encode $(2^{32} - 2^{24})^2 = 18302910360610406400$ 2D coordinates )

I'm trying to understand the answer... the last instructions under "Alternatively", what is or how do I do G "green" 0 "grey"?

@GordonBrinkmann thanks for feedback, it was supposed to be left mouse button but apparently it's not clear, I'll have to change it with something else. There's a Gorgious script somewhere, that uses graphical icons, but unfortunately that requires either adding the image address in each spot or modifying the message at bottom addying a reference to the image, which makes it too hard to use a simple macro for it. YOU'D THINK WITH SO MANY EMOJIS, THEY WOULD CREATE A FEW FOR MOUSE ICONS! P.S. Actually that's Gandalf's update to older CodemanX's script. I'll try installing it.

@GordonBrinkmann I changed it to an icon, what do you think?

Okay, now I recognize it  I never know how to show a mouse, so I stick with just writing "left-click" or use LMB like others do sometimes.

Thanks, that's an interesting workaround. I'll give this some consideration if it turns out those two inputs are honestly locked to +/- 10, with no way to change it.
